# Unable to call a EJB class from my JSP file

Tags: jsp

I am trying to run a project with JSP and EJB and in the following code

```
An error occurred at line: [5] in the jsp file: [/catalog.jsp]
Catalog cannot be resolved to a type
2: <body>
3: <%@ page  import="javax.ejb.*,javax.naming.*,java.util.*,java.io.*,project.server.*,java.sql.*" %>
4: 
5: <%! Catalog catalog; %>
6: <%! CatalogHome catalogHome; %>
7: <%! ResultSet resultSet;%>
8: <%! Context context; %>


An error occurred at line: [6] in the jsp file: [/catalog.jsp]
CatalogHome cannot be resolved to a type
3: <%@ page  import="javax.ejb.*,javax.naming.*,java.util.*,java.io.*,project.server.*,java.sql.*" %>
4: 
5: <%! Catalog catalog; %>
6: <%! CatalogHome catalogHome; %>
7: <%! ResultSet resultSet;%>
8: <%! Context context; %>
9: <%!

import javax.ejb.*;
import java.rmi.*;

public interface CatalogHome extends EJBHome
{
public Catalog create() throws RemoteException,CreateException;
}

import javax.ejb.*;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.sql.*;
public interface Catalog extends  EJBObject
{
public ResultSet getProducts() throws RemoteException;
}
```

It is unable to locate the classes whereas the same are in the same folder as the JSP files. How can i make it work?